# Break a tensorflow.while_loop conditionally

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to modify the GPT-2 sample generating code from nshepperd's fork (https://github.com/nshepperd/gpt-2).

Specifically the code below which is part of the sample.py file:

```
with tf.name_scope('sample_sequence'):
    # Don't feed the last context token -- leave that to the loop below
    # TODO: Would be slightly faster if we called step on the entire context,
    # rather than leaving the last token transformer calculation to the while loop.
    context_output = step(hparams, context[:, :-1])

    def body(past, prev, output):
        next_outputs = step(hparams, prev[:, tf.newaxis], past=past)
        logits = next_outputs['logits'][:, -1, :]  / tf.to_float(temperature)
        if penalize > 0.0:
            logits = penalize_used(logits, output, penalize=penalize)
        if top_p > 0.0:
            logits = top_p_logits(logits, p=top_p, epsilon=epsilon)
        else:
            logits = top_k_logits(logits, k=top_k, epsilon=epsilon)
        samples = tf.multinomial(logits, num_samples=1, output_dtype=tf.int32)
        return [
            tf.concat([past, next_outputs['presents']], axis=-2),
            tf.squeeze(samples, axis=[1]),
            tf.concat([output, samples], axis=1),
        ]

    def cond(*args):
        return True

    _, _, tokens = tf.while_loop(
        cond=cond, body=body,
        maximum_iterations=length,
        loop_vars=[
            context_output['presents'],
            context[:, -1],
            context,
        ],
        shape_invariants=[
            tf.TensorShape(model.past_shape(hparams=hparams, batch_size=batch_size)),
            tf.TensorShape([batch_size]),
            tf.TensorShape([batch_size, None]),
        ],
        back_prop=False,
    )

    return tokens
```

Essentially what I am trying to do is make it stop once it has generated a token with a specific value, e.g. !EndText!. However, as I am very new to tensorflow I am very uncertain about how to do this, especially as the official documentation on this is slightly sparse. If I understand correctly, I need to modify the cond function (which I understand to loop over all the outputs of the body function) so that it breaks if enc.decode(output)=="!EndText!" however I am more or less at a complete loss on where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer (through significant help from someone who is way more familiar with TF than me).

Only modification that is needed is to remove "return True" under cond and instead insert the following return statement

`return tf.math.logical_and(tf.not_equal(output[0][-1], tf.cast(X, tf.int32)), tf.not_equal(output[0][-2], tf.cast(Y, tf.int32)))`

where X and Y represent (in this case) two tokens that should signal a stop, if you want fewer or more tokens (i.e. if your tokens that signal a stop are less/more distinct), just add/remove terms in the logical_and statement above.